# Why are VW tail light bulbs listed as 12W / 5W?

Tags: vw, lights, tail-lights, polo, bulbs

My VW Polo 6R left tail light is off and it seems there are several kinds of bulbs available for purchase:

```
12V 5W
12V 12W
12V 5W + 12V 12W
12V 12W + 5V 5W
...
```

My first guess is that the 5V is just a mistake on the listing. But what are the bulbs that are listed as a combination of 5W and 12W for ? Do they draw different currents when the engine is on/off ?

Comment: Are you sure it is 12W and not 21W?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it is a 21W/5W bulb, then it has 2 filaments of different brightness.

The 5W filament is for the side/tail light for night driving.

The 21W filament is for bright illumination when you press the brake pedal.

[image: Image copied from ToolStation]

Image copied from [ToolStation](https://www.toolstation.com/brake-tail-light-bulb/p72384?store=S4&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=googleshoppingfeed&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3tmdrZCy5QIVSrDtCh3cOgJ3EAQYASABEgIjBfD_BwE)

Comment: Maybe Polo lights are 12W not 21W. Site is .ro but google translate works well: http://www.onauto.ro/catalog/fisa/32813#ramura=Lumini&subramura=Bec%2C+lampa+spate . But according to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hqpx9TcvLZ8 the brake light (0:15) and tail light (1:30) seem to use different bulbs.

Comment: I believe this site shows this same bulb for your car - https://www.autodoc.co.uk/car-parts/combination-rearlight-bulb-11595/vw/polo/polo-6r-6c